# Class member function at() and switch statements with a loop

Tags: c++, switch-statement, class-members

This is my first time posting here, so apologies in advance if I'm doing something wrong.I'm working on a project where a part of the program needs to translate a phone word (IE "Rad-Code") into corresponding phone digits (IE 723-2633). I'm trying to use a switch statement along with at() and length() class member functions. I've tried switching up the order of my code for this section, but it keeps giving me an error stating: "Enter the phone word: Rad-Code 723-2633terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at: __n (which is 8) >= this->size() (which is 8)"

Here's the code in question:

```
else if (choice == PHONE_WORD)
{
        cout << "\nEnter the phone word: ";
        cin >> phoneWord;
        /*while (phoneWord.length() != 8)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid phone number length: ";
            getline(cin, phoneWord);
        }*/

        for (int i = 0; i < phoneWord.length(); i++)
        switch (phoneWord.at(i))
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                cout << "2";
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'd':
            case 'E':
            case 'e':
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                cout << "3";
                break;
            case 'G':
            case 'g':
            case 'H':
            case 'h':
            case 'I':
            case 'i':
                cout << "4";
                break;
            case 'J':
            case 'j':
            case 'K':
            case 'k':
            case 'L':
            case 'l':
                cout << "5";
                break;
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
            case 'N':
            case 'n':
            case 'O':
            case 'o':
                cout << "6";
                break;
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
            case 'Q':
            case 'q':
            case 'R':
            case 'r':
            case 'S':
            case 's':
                cout << "7";
                break;
            case 'T':
            case 't':
            case 'U':
            case 'u':
            case 'V':
            case 'v':
                cout << "8";
                break;
            case 'W':
            case 'w':
            case 'X':
            case 'x':
            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
            case 'Z':
            case 'z':
                cout << "9";
                break;
            case '-':
                cout << "-";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Please enter a valid input: ";
                break;
        }

        cout << phoneWord << " translates to " << phoneWord.at(0) << phoneWord.at(1) << phoneWord.at(2) << phoneWord.at(3) << phoneWord.at(4) << phoneWord.at(5) << phoneWord.at(6) << phoneWord.at(8) << ".";
}
```

Comment: And here's the entire program:

Comment: You don't check length here: `phoneWord.at(6) << phoneWord.at(8)`  If the string is 8 letters long the valid indices are 0-7.  You might consider a loop, it's less error prone and doesn't count on a specific size.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick response. I'm trying to do a loop, but I'm not sure where to start it. I'm trying to use the "for" loop in a makeshift array, but that might be where my issues are coming from. Also, I accidentally entered 8 instead of 7. 

Wow, I just tried it, and I'm definitely getting further. There are some additional things I need to correct, of course, but that was such a simple overlook. I really appreciate it! I'm still working on this section, so I may have some additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem: `phoneWord.at(8)`. Should be `phoneWord.at(7).

Here's a more concise way of achieving your intent:

```
// DIGIT_MAP is a static map of characters to digits, 'a' -> 0, 'q' -> 7 etc.
for (auto it = phoneWord.cbegin(); it != phoneWord.cend(); ++it)
   cout << DIGIT_MAP[tolower(*it)];
```

No need to use `at`, this is what iterators are for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that [`std::vector::at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) throws an exception if the index is out of range:

> It throws `out_of_range` if `n` is out of bounds.

As [@Retired Ninja points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40569452/class-member-function-at-and-switch-statements-with-a-loop#comment68375315_40569452): your final `cout` statement doesn't check the index before accessing the element

```
cout << phoneWord << " translates to " << phoneWord.at(0) << phoneWord.at(1) << phoneWord.at(2) << phoneWord.at(3) << phoneWord.at(4) << phoneWord.at(5) << phoneWord.at(6) << phoneWord.at(8) << ".";
```

It's likely that final `phoneWord.at(8)` was meant to be `phoneWord.at(7)`, but you can simplify this to prevent these issues like so:

```
std::cout << phoneWord << " translates to ";
for (auto c : phoneWord)
    std::cout << c;
std::cout << "." << std::endl;
```

This will safely iterate through all values in `phoneWord` and you won't need to worry about accessing elements out of range. It works safely if there are 4, 8 or 20 characters in `phoneWord`